# If Exist And Else in batch

Tags: batch-file

How would I add and Else option into this to say:
*You don't have the java dev kit please select option 4?*

```
FOR /R "C:\Program Files" %%a IN (.) DO (
    IF EXIST "%%~a\javac.exe" ECHO You Have The Java Dev Kit Ignore Option 4
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search fist all subdirectories to decide if it's there.

```
set found=0
FOR /R "C:\Program Files" %%a IN (.) DO (
    IF EXIST "%%~a\javac.exe" set found=1
)
if %found%==0 (
   ECHO You don't have the java dev kit please select option 4
) ELSE (
   echo Found javac.exe
)
```

Comment: You've forgotten about `ECHO You Have The Java Dev Kit Ignore Option 4`

Comment: set found=0
FOR /R "C:\Program Files" %%a IN (.) DO (
    IF EXIST "%%~a\javac.exe" set found=1
)
if %found%==0 ECHO You don't have the java dev kit please select option 4
if %found%==1 Echo You have java Dev Kit please ignore option 4

Would something like that work?

Comment: Yes, it's nearly the same as my answer, only without using `ELSE`

Answer (score 0):

```
SET found=0
FOR /R "C:\Program Files" %%a IN (.) DO (
    IF EXIST "%%~a\javac.exe" ( ECHO You Have The Java Dev Kit Ignore Option 4 
    SET found=1)
) 
IF %found%==0 ( ECHO You don't have the java dev kit please select option 4 )
```

If you want ELSE you must use `(` and `)` brackets.

Comment: This will display one text for each subdirectory

Comment: Fixed, but the OP asked for ELSE, not for fixing.

Comment: :-) Not fixed, as `SET %found%=0` will not work. Setting a variable is done without the percent signs

Comment: @up: fixed, I'm on Linux so I don't have way to test it.