# If/else command syntax in batch editing

Tags: batch-file

How can I add an `ELSE` part to this code so that if it can't find `javac.exe` it will give the appropriate *Cannot Find JDK* message??

```
 FOR /R "C:\Program Files" %%a IN (.) DO (
        IF EXIST "%%~a\javac.exe" ECHO You Have The Java Dev Kit Ignore 

    Option 4)
```

Comment: A quick google search brought up the following link:  http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntif.php

Comment: You already asked [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324685/if-exist-and-else-in-batch) about it, and you got your answer. Or didn't you?

Answer (score 3):

You can add some brackets to you IF statment, and add the ELSE afterwards

```
IF EXIST "%%~a\javac.exe" (
        ECHO You Have The Java Dev Kit Ignore 
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO Cannot Find JDK
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  IF EXIST "%%~a\javac.exe" (ECHO You Have The Java Dev Kit Ignore) ELSE ( do something else )
```